# Tracking Google Spreadsheet Add On Installation Using Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-sheets, google-apps-marketplace

I have a Google Spreadsheet AddOn published on [Google Apps Marketplace](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/), and I've added a link to the app on my website. I need to track how many users have installed my add on that came via my website.

How do I do it via Google Analytics?

Help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to set up google analytics in your add-on via HTMLService and then set up cross domain linking in the analytics to make hit's from your add-on visible to your site's Analyitcs.
below there is a screenshot of GA (actually GTM) code inside Supermetrics AddOn

[image: below there is a screenshot of GA (actually GTM) code inside Supermetrics AddOn:]

Comment: I want to track how many users have come via my website to the GSuite Marketplace and installed my addon instead of tracking how many are using my addon